# Android - Registering touches on two different zones of the screen separately

Tags: android, motionevent

Basically, I just want to know when there is a touch on the left side of the screen, or right side of the screen, or both. I know how to retrieve the action of the event by using .getAction(), but this doesn't work; when one side is already pressed the other will not register. This happens even if I do this:

    `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
    Log.d("playerState","Screen pressed down");
    }`

Is there any way to just detect the x and y coordinates of every touch on the screen at a given instant? That would make life a lot easier.

Comment: MotionEvent has x and y coordinates, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't detecting the second touch at all it seems, so I don't have its x and y coordinates.
To clarify, the code up there isn't logging "Screen pressed down" when I press on the left side of the screen if I was pressing the right side of the screen also.

Comment: You might want to search about handling multi-touch gestures on Android.